# How to get value from drop-down menu?

Tags: sql, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I need to print to PDF a form using SQL query. I've got problem with getting value which is located in drop-down menu. It looks like that:

[image]

(Waluta and Forma platnosci are drop-down menu types).

Variables like date or number I'm getting in that way:

```
SELECT
ga.number 
FROM GlobalAttribute ga 
INNER JOIN globalattributetype gat 
    ON gat.Id = ga.GlobalAttributeTypeId 
WHERE GlobalElementId=$TRIGGERVALUE 
    AND gat.systemkey = ’BT_AMMOUNT’
```

But how to get 'Waluta' or 'Forma platnosci'?

Comment: I'd take a look through the GlobalAttribute and GlobalAttributeType to see what you would need to change in the WHERE statement to get what you're after. Without knowing what's in those tables it's going to be tough for anybody to give you a good answer.